# Can custom keyboard access user photos?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios-app-extension

I'm looking to make a custom keyboard for iOS that accesses a user's camera roll. Is this possible? I've done a bit of research but it doesn't seem like a custom keyboard extension can access the camera roll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom keyboard extension *can* access the camera roll, provided the user has already given full access; all the same code that works in a normal app should work in a keyboard extension as well. Per the documentation:

> If you request open access by setting this key’s value to YES, your keyboard gains the following capabilities, each with a concomitant responsibility in terms of user trust:
>
> Access to Location Services, the Address Book database, and the Camera Roll, each requiring user permission on first access

I believe that Riffsy has a feature where you can save to and recover GIFs from the camera roll.